# Twilio video participant track not loading to dom

Tags: javascript, dom, video, twilio, webrtc

I'm following the example from the [quickstart tutorial](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js/blob/1.x/quickstart/src/index.js)

Basically my local video works fine, but when a participant joins the room I can't seem to add the track to a DOM element because the format of the object is different.

line 13 has:
`container.appendChild(track.attach());`

But I get the following error on a participant joining:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: track.attach is not a function`

This is because the structure of the `RemoteVideoTrackPublication` object (parsed as `track` above) contains the object 'track' within it, so it *should really* be `container.appendChild(track.track.attach());` for the participant object.. HOWEVER

This **only** works from the JS console. I can attach the video stream AFTER this error occurs from the client-side JS console - but no matter what I try, I cannot seem to be able to add the track normally because the `attach.()` function doesn't seem to exist on the `track` object.

Is this a simple DOM or ordering of events issue?

Comment: Showing a bit of your code will be helpful

Comment: It would be useful to see more of the code you are using here. Also, please note that the quickstart tutorial uses version 1.x of Twilio Video and I believe `RemoteVideoTrackPublication` objects are part of version 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and i fixed it when i update twilio to version 2 and change code after connect

```
room.participants.forEach(function (participant) {
     console.log('Remote Participant connected: ', participant);

     participant.tracks.forEach(function (publication) {
        if (publication.isSubscribed) {
            const track = publication.track;
            document.getElementById('co-browsing-remote-screen').appendChild(track.attach());
        }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
room.participants.forEach(function(participant) {
    let previewContainer = document.getElementById('remoteTrack');
    participant.on('trackSubscribed', track => {
       previewContainer.appendChild(track.attach());
    });
});
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. For future readers, it's far more interesting to see explained why this answers the question. And answers with explanations tend to have better acceptance.